# Microsoft Edge Extension Auth0 implementation - Authorization page could not be loaded

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, auth0, microsoft-edge-extension

I already successfully implemented Auth0 in Chrome Extension which is available in Chrome Store, and now I'm trying to convert this extension for Microsoft Edge. 
On the extension side, code is completely the same.
I update `Allowed Origins (CORS)`, `Allowed Callback URLs` and the rest of settings in Auth0 dashboard in the same way I did with Chrome Extension using key from Microsoft Store, but I keep getting this error when I try to login from extension :

`Authorization page could not be loaded.`

Are there any specific settings for Edge Extensions, as they introduced them recently?

Answer (score 1):

The information you provided above is not enough for reproducing the issue and check the issue. We are not available with the subscription of Auth0 to make a test.

I can see that you are using [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) which is a third party product.

I checked its documentation and found that the Chrome browser is fully supported but the Edge browser may have some issues.

[image]

I also found that many users who are using Auth0 had similar errors before. So, in this case, it is possible that the issue related to Auth0. I suggest you try to contact the official support of Auth0. so if the issue is caused by this product then they can help you to identify it.

References:

1. [Auth0 Product Support Matrix](https://auth0.com/docs/support/matrix)
2. [Auth0 Community](https://github.com/auth0-community)
3. [Auth0 + Chrome extension - Authorization Page Could not be loaded](https://community.auth0.com/t/auth0-chrome-extension-authorization-page-could-not-be-loaded/24261)